# How to pass shell variable into awk

Tags: git, bash, shell, awk

I have a bunch of remote branches on my git server that all start w/ the same prefix

```
  origin/feature/100-use-email-to-get-all-sockets
  origin/feature/101-remove-buttons-on-response
  origin/feature/102-delete-removes-from-store
  origin/feature/103-erik-fix-moderator-logged-multiple-times-when-logged-in-as-admin-and-client
  origin/feature/31-client-accordian-list-on-admin-side
  origin/feature/33-video-skin-ios
  ...
```

quite frequently I need to clean up the server and purge all the old-outdated branches

I'm trying to write a script, but I want the ability to pass in a variable that I want to target instead of hard coding like "feature", "bug", etc...

How can I incorporate this variable into this command?  all the examples I've found seem to fail.

```
TGT=feature
git branch -r | awk -F/ '/\/feature/{print $3}'
```

What I'm looking for is something like

```
TGT=feature
git branch -r | awk -F/ '/\/$TGT/{print $3}'
```

Comment: Use `-v` to give shell variables to awk: `awk -v myvar=$your_var '{...}'` etc

Comment: @fedorqui does variable expansion works within `//`?

Comment: I already tried playing w/ the -v flag but  that didn't seem to work.  I think my syntax in the quoted portion was incorrect

Comment: @AvinashRaj I think not, but you can write `awk -v myvar="$yourvar" '$0 ~ myvar'` If you want regex matching

Comment: @AvinashRaj exactly what user000001 said. You can test for example `awk -v v="el" '/v/' file` does not work, while `awk -v v="el" '$0 ~ v' file` does. (sample file contains `hello` and `bye`).

Comment: @fedorqui haha yep, i know.